# iOS - Struggling with casting between Obj-C / Swift code

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data, casting, swift4

I have been translating some part of my App from Obj-C to Swift and I am facing an issue that I can't understand or bypass.

*Take a look at this Objective-C classes :*

**The Model Class Forecast**

```
@class City;

@interface Forecast : ForecastInterface

@property (nonatomic, retain) City *city;

@end
```

**The Model Class Forecast48h**

```
@class City;

@interface Forecast48h : ForecastInterface

@property (nonatomic, retain) City *city;

@end
```

**The Model Class Summary**

```
@class City;

@interface Summary : ForecastInterface

@property (nonatomic, retain) City *city;

@end
```

and finally

**The Model ForecastInterface**

```
@interface ForecastInterface : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * descriptionLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * windDirection;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * seaState;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * day;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * probFreeze;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * probSnow;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * probRain;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * tempMap;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * tmpMax;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * tmpSea;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * tmpMin;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * speedWind;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * endDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * startDate;

@end
```

Ok now you have the presentation of my CoreData model.

I want to understand why I can't cast Forecast or Forecast48h type to Summary type ?

***Look at this example :***

```
var listForecasts = Array<Any>()

self.listForecasts = city.bestForecastArray()
```

This is an Objective-C method in order to fetch some Forecast or Forecast48 objects and return an NSArray.

```
-(NSArray *)bestForecastArray;
```

Now the part where I am struggling.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell
        cell?.layoutIfNeeded()

        var tmpForecast = self.listForecasts[indexPath.row]

        cell?.delegate = self
        cell?.load(tmpForecast as! Summary)

        return cell!
    }
```

When I dump the listForecasts it only contain Forecast and Forecast48h objects.

And when I want to load my cell, I have runtime error :

> Could not cast value of type 'Forecast48h_Forecast48h_'  to 'Summary'

First of all why this double Forecast48h type in the error message ?

The prototype of the load method :

```
-(void)loadCell:(Summary*)weatherSummary;
```

I really need to pass a Summary object to the loadCell method.
Why this is accepted in Objective-C but not in Swift ?

Take a look at this code working written in Objective-C :

```
Summary* aSummary = [_listForecasts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell setDelegate:self];
[cell loadCell:aSummary];
return cell;
```

This worked in Objective-C .

Any help? Don't hesitate to ask additional informations. The project is complex, hard to explain I tried to make it as simple as possible.

**EDIT:**

```
@interface Summary (Additions)

+(NSArray*)allSummaryOfCity:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context city:(City*)aCity;

+(NSArray *)arrayInformationsWithSummary:(Summary*)aSummary;

+(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchControllerForAllSummaryOfCity:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context cityIndicatif:(NSString*)anIndicatifCity;
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymorphism means that you can always cast an object to its superclass type, but if two objects have a type that derive from the same superclass, you can't cast from one type to another. In the case of protocols, the same is valid.

In your case it's enough to use the *ForecastInterface* type, since you are sure that any fetched object implements the *ForecastInterface* protocol:

```
var listForecasts = Array<ForecastInterface>()
self.listForecasts = city.bestForecastArray()

...

-(void)loadCell:(ForecastInterface*)weatherSummary;

...


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell
    cell?.layoutIfNeeded()

    // tmpForecast type: ForeCastInterface
    var tmpForecast = self.listForecasts[indexPath.row]

    cell?.delegate = self
    cell?.load(tmpForecast)

    return cell!
}
```

Change your methods in a way that they should deal *ForecastInterface* types instead of *Summary* types.

**Edit**

If you need to use methods that are only in the *Summary* class, then you have two solutions: (1) move these methods in the *ForeCastInterface* protocol, or (2) try a cast to *Summary* and call the methods only if the object is really of type *Summary*, without forcing the cast:

```
var tmpForecast = self.listForecasts[indexPath.row]
if let summary = tmpForecast as? Summary {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is it possible at some time to go back from a ForecastInterface type to a Summary type ?

Comment: @Balanced Only if the object is really of type Summary. If the object is of type Forecast48h, the cast will always fail. It would succeed if Forecast48 was a subclass of Summary, which isn't your case.

Comment: I mean I changed my loadCell method in order to deal with ForecastInterface type now. But in this method I really need some specific methods from the Summary type implemented in the Summary+Additions file.

Comment: Which methods do you need? could you please post the contents of Summary+Additions.swift?

Comment: @Balanced Ok in this case you either have to move these methods in the *ForecastInterface* protocol, or to try a (non-forced) conversion (see the edit).

Comment: If you force the cast, in case that you have another object type (e.g. *Forecast48h*), the app will crash.